# Simulate "Swipe to Unlock" in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to create a "Swipe to Unlock" feature in Unity 3D ( just like the one in iPhone lock screen). I tried the followings:

**Part 1 - Detect Swipe**

I'm able to detect a swipe using the following codes:

```
private bool couldBeSwipe = false;
private float minSwipeDistance = 14;
private float maxSwipeTime = 10;
private float comfortZone = 100;
private float startTime;
private Vector2 startPos;
const int SWIPE_NONE = 0;
const int SWIPE_UP = 1;
const int SWIPE_RIGHT = 2;
const int SWIPE_DOWN = 3;
const int SWIPE_LEFT = 4;
private int swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
```

In `void Update()`:

```
    // Input
    swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.touches [0];
        switch (touch.phase) {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            couldBeSwipe = true;
            startPos = touch.position;
            startTime = Time.time;
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            if ((Mathf.Abs (touch.position.y - startPos.y) > comfortZone) && (Mathf.Abs (touch.position.x - startPos.x) > comfortZone)) {
                couldBeSwipe = false;
            }
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Ended:
            float swipeTime = Time.time - startTime;
            float swipeDistance = (touch.position - startPos).magnitude;
            float deltaX = touch.position.x - startPos.x;
            float deltaY = touch.position.y - startPos.y;

            if (couldBeSwipe && (swipeTime < maxSwipeTime) && (swipeDistance > minSwipeDistance)) { 
                if (Mathf.Abs (deltaX) > comfortZone) {
                    float swipeDirectionY = Mathf.Sign(deltaX);
                    if (swipeDirectionY == 1) {
                        swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_RIGHT;
                    } else {
                        swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_LEFT;
                    }
                }
                if (Mathf.Abs (deltaY) > comfortZone) {
                      float swipeDirectionY = Mathf.Sign(deltaY);
                      if (swipeDirectionY == 1) {
                            swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_UP;
                  } else {
                            swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_DOWN;
                  }
                }
            } else if (swipeTime > maxSwipeTime) {
                Debug.Log ("Too slow");
                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
            } else if (swipeDistance < minSwipeDistance) {
                Debug.Log ("Too short");
                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
            } else if (!couldBeSwipe) {
                Debug.Log ("Not a swipe");
                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
            } else {
                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

**Part 2 - Move a Texture (with axis constraint)**

There are several ways to move a Texture, including `GUI.DragWindow()`, `GUI.Box()`, etc. But none is directly moving a `Texture`. Which is the simplest way to move a Texture along an axis. For example, constraint its movement only on X-axis ?

Comment: Attach the image to a slider's Node then no matter (Or limit if you want) where your finger is on screen you can only move it on axis that the slider is on then have the slider value become 0 on finger realise if it isnt above x amount and if it is above x amount then unlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In respect to using Unity GUI, there's no 'movement' you're constantly redrawing or sending a redraw message each time you call a GUI element inside of OnGUI() {} e.g. GUI.Button

If you wanted to use OnGUI, i'd construct the movement as follows;

I've moulded you're functions and written this class;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SelectStageScene : MonoBehaviour {

    // You'll want to set this;
    public Texture2D        screenTexture;

    private float           minSwipeDistance        = 14;
    private float           maxSwipeTime            = 10;
    private float           startTime;

    private Vector2         startPos;
    private Vector2         currentPos;

    const int               SWIPE_NONE              = 0;
    const int               SWIPE_UP                = 1;
    const int               SWIPE_RIGHT             = 2;
    const int               SWIPE_DOWN              = 3;
    const int               SWIPE_LEFT              = 4;
    private int             swipeDirection          = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;

    private Vector2         screenTextureOffset     = Vector2.zero;
    private float           fadeAlpha               = 0f;
    private float           fadeSpeed               = 1f; // How fast the texture fades after swipe.

    public void Update() {
        // If no swipe direction is set.
        if ( swipeDirection == SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE ) {
            // To fade back in after swipe (just to complete the loop)
            if ( fadeAlpha > 0 ) {
                fadeAlpha -= Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed;
            }
            // Getting input
            if ( Input.touchCount > 0 ) {
                Touch touch = Input.touches [0];
                switch ( touch.phase ) {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    startPos = touch.position;
                    startTime = Time.time;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    currentPos = touch.position;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    screenTextureOffset = currentPos - startPos;

                    // By using swipe distance as a magnitude here, regardless of x or y axis, we'll be choosing a swipe direction.
                    // If we were only interested in X axis we would use screenTextureOffset.x instead of swipeDistance
                    if ( Time.time - startTime < maxSwipeTime && ( currentPos - startPos ).magnitude > minSwipeDistance ) {
                        // Find if we've moved more on the x-axis or y-axis.
                        if ( Mathf.Abs( screenTextureOffset.x ) > Mathf.Abs( screenTextureOffset.y ) ) {
                            // x-axis
                            if ( screenTextureOffset.x > 0 ) {
                                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_RIGHT;
                            } else {
                                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_LEFT;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // y-axis
                            if ( screenTextureOffset.y > 0 ) {
                                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_UP;
                            } else {
                                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_DOWN;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                screenTextureOffset *= 1 - Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed;
            }
        } else {
            // This fades the texture and moves it further in direction of swipe.
            screenTextureOffset *= 1 + Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed;
            fadeAlpha += Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed;
            if ( fadeAlpha > 1 ) {
                swipeDirection = SelectStageScene.SWIPE_NONE;
                Debug.Log( "Finished swipe movement : " + swipeDirection );
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        GUI.color = Color.white - Color.black * fadeAlpha;
        GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect( screenTextureOffset.x, screenTextureOffset.y, Screen.width, Screen.height ), screenTexture );
        /*// Specific axis. Constraining visually leaves easy potential access later on.
        if ( Mathf.Abs( screenTextureOffset.x ) > Mathf.Abs( screenTextureOffset.y ) ) {
            // x-axis
            GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect( screenTextureOffset.x, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height ), screenTexture );
        } else {
            // y-axis
            GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect( 0, screenTextureOffset.y, Screen.width, Screen.height ), screenTexture );
        }
        */
    }

}
```